# What is the concept behind namespacing?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I know the basic concepts of JavaScript well, but I am having trouble understanding some of the advanced concepts. The concept I am wondering about is namespacing. When is it useful? How should I use it? I'd appreciate any explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer using an example.

You want to pad a number so it's `2` digits long,

```
function pad(x) {
    return ('00' + x).slice(-2);
}
pad(3); // "03"
```

You have some other code on the website that pads numbers `n` digits long

```
function pad(x, n) {
    x = '' + x;
    n = n + 1 - x.length;
    if (n < 0) n = 0;
    return new Array(n).join('0') + x;
}
pad(3, 5); // "00003"
```

Now what happens if you have these two pieces of code on the same page?
With the order they're in at the moment, you'll get

```
pad(3); // RangeError: Invalid array length
```

because the functions have the same name, so the wrong one gets used.

How can you avoid these kinds of problems? Namespaces! If you put all of your code into a namespace, the only conflict you have to worry about is of the chosen name for your namespace, everything else is named according to that so won't conflict.

---

Namespaces in *JavaScript* can be achieved in a great many ways, but usually boil down to adding properties to an *Object*

```
// make an Object to be your namespace
var myNamespace = {};
// define your thing of interest within namespace
myNamespace.pad = function (x) {return ('00' + x).slice(-2);};
// and then use it
myNamespace.pad(3); // "03"
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add an example on creating the namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about when it is useful, one scenario where using namespaces in JavaScript can be essential is **when you are using other JavaScript libraries**. You want to avoid naming conflicts between your code and their code, and among them.

To quote [Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) in a detailed discussion of this issue:

> In JavaScript, namespacing at an enterprise level is critical as it's important to safeguard your code from breaking in the event of another script on the page using the same variable or method names as you are. With the number of third-party tags regularly injected into pages these days, this can be a common problem we all need to tackle at some point in our careers. As a well-behaved 'citizen' of the global namespace, it's also imperative that you do your best to similarly not prevent other developer's scripts executing due to the same issues.

Comment: Thanks. I have been through tutorial, but I still don't understand how to implement it. How do you do that?

Comment: So is namespacing just storing all of the names locally and protecting from outside sources?

Comment: @user2297366 In Javascript You just create an object with unique name (namespace) and then put your code into that object (namespace). To avoid naming conflicts between your code and their code, and among them, as DOK said. So when you want use some piece of code you can make something like this... `someSpecialName.myObjectName.myMethod();`

Comment: @user2297366: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+how+to+create+namespace `;)`.